# Hide ACF Metabox on page edit but show on post edit

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have a bit of a unique issue that I've been struggling with all weekend and hopefully someone can help shed some light here.. I have several ACF groups that I've specified to show on both posts and pages edit page.  Although I am storing values (programmatically) in the ACF fields on pages, I need to hide that group on the pages edit screen but still show it in the post edit screen.

The following code works until I try to find a condition that identifies if user is on the page edit screen rather than the post edit screen

```
function my_remove_meta_boxes() {
if ( get_post_type() == 'page' ) 
{
    $out = '';
    $out .= '<style>#acf-group_61699b806807f {display: none !important;}    </style>';
            
    echo $out;
}
}
add_action( 'admin_menu' , 'my_remove_meta_boxes' );
```

if tried get_current_screen, is_page, and get_post_type but nothing seems to work.  Any help would be huge.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to use `get_current_screen()` function it will give you screen object and you'll match the screen id in if statment.

you also need to use `admin_head` to write your custom css with `style` tag.

The code will be like this:

```
function vh_acf_remove_meta_boxes() {
    $screen    = get_current_screen();
    $screen_id = $screen->id ? $screen->id : '';

    if ( 'page' === $screen_id ) {
        echo '<style>#acf-group_61699b806807f {display: none !important;}</style>';
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_head', 'vh_acf_remove_meta_boxes' );
```